# Ruby CSV - Trying to wrap output in double quotes, getting """Hello World""" instead of "Hello World"

Tags: ruby, csv

```
require 'csv'
s = "\"Hello World\""

CSV.open('output.txt', 'w') do |csv|
    csv << [s]
end
```

Inside my file, I get:

```
"""Hello World"""
```

What's with the extra quotes, and what is the correct way to do this? I don't want all fields wrapped in quotes, just some. Using ruby 1.9.3p194

Comment: in open office i get the format you're looking for, didn't put the effort to do screen capture, but it works for me

Comment: if you output to a .txt file, or open the .csv in a text editor, it will have the incorrect output. I'm not sure why opening the .csv in a spreadsheet app shows the correct thing. I also get the correct output viewing with Excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct. [Quote characters are escaped in CSV files by doubling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples). And all fields that contain commas, newlines and/or quote characters need to be enclosed in quotes.

So the first quote starts a quoted field, the second and third quote encode the actual quote character.

[image: Excel screenshot]

becomes

```
Hello,"Field, with comma","2"" by 4""",123
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way to change this behavior? In my actual project, I'm attempting to output pipe-delimted .txt files, and I need certain descriptive fields to be wrapped in just one set of double qoutes to be accepted by the target application. Its the LEDES law invoice format.

Comment: @codeself: Well, yes, but then you can't use `csv` because that's not a CSV file any more. Just join the strings by `|` and wrap the descriptive fields in quotes manually before that.